# Comparing fields with same degree

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Two part question: Are the fields $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}, i \sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}, i, \sqrt{3})$ identical in algebraic structure? I have in notes that they both have degree of 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

How do I show explicitly that $\mathbb{Q} ( i \sqrt{3})$ is only degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$. The usual trick is to adjoin the real roots and then adjoin the complex root, but it's a different story when it's not just $i$ by itself.

Edit: I'm starting to mistrust that the degree of the two extensions are identical.

Comment: The latter is simpler. Show that $x^2+3$ is the minimal polynomial of $i\sqrt 3$ over $\Bbb Q.$

Comment: I have that for a rational prime $p$ and any $n>1$ the polynomial $x^n - p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can I take $p=-3$?

Comment: Probably. Another way would be to show that $x^2+3$ has no real roots, so certainly can't be split into two linear factors over the rationals.

Comment: Not meaning to nitpick but you should be more specific than "identical in algebraic structures". What type of structure? Both being degree 6 over Q immediately gives they are isomorphic as vector spaces over Q, which you really want to show they are isomorphic as fields, which requires you to show an inclusion as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, neither $i$ nor $\sqrt{3}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$. And I think you're right to mistrust that the degrees are equal since $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i,\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}|=12$.